# poner imagenes en jlabels sin repetir

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Buenas tardes compañeros, estoy realizando una función que cuando se seleccionen un item del combobox, me ponga las 8 imágenes en cada jlabel, tengo 8 Jlabel y en cada una se debe presentar una imagen diferente dependiendo del genero que se tome.

```
tengo un array de strings por cada genero, aquí solo se visualiza un array de `accion`.

public class GUI_Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {
String accion[] = {"/imagenes/p1.jpg","/imagenes/p2.jpg","/imagenes/p3.jpg","/imagenes/p4.jpg","/imagenes/p5.jpg","/imagenes/p6.jpg"};

aqui esta el evento del combobox, del cual se toma el texto y dependiendo este se situan imagenes en cada jlabel. Se deberian tomar todas las imagenes del array seleccionado y ubicarlas e cada jlabel, el problema es que no se ubican asi, sino se repite una sola imagen del array en todos los jlabels.

private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String genero = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    switch(genero){
        case "Acción":
            int r1 = (int) (Math.random() * accion.length);
            URL url1 = this.getClass().getResource(accion[r1]);
            try {
                Image img1 = ImageIO.read(url1);
                jblV1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
                jblV2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
                jblV3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
                jblV4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
                jblV5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
                jblV6.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
                jblV7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
                jblV8.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            break;
    }
   
}
```

necesito que lea cada imagen del array `accion` y que no se repitan las imágenes cuando se ubiquen en cada `jlabel`, si me pudiesen guiar para resolver de antemano les agradezco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas que no se repiten no debes usar un valor aleatorio que obtienes mediante:

```
  int r1 = (int) (Math.random() * accion.length);
```

deberías usar el indice 0 hasta la cantidad de imágenes en el array:

```
private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            

    String genero = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    switch(genero){
        case "Acción":
            //int r1 = (int) (Math.random() * accion.length);
            //URL url1 = this.getClass().getResource(accion[r1]);
        try {
            int i = 0;
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource(accion[i++]);
            Image img1 = ImageIO.read(url);
            jblV1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
            url = this.getClass().getResource(accion[i++]);
            Image img2 = ImageIO.read(url);
            jblV2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
            url = this.getClass().getResource(accion[i++]);
            Image img3 = ImageIO.read(url);
            jblV3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img3));
            url = this.getClass().getResource(accion[i++]);
            Image img4 = ImageIO.read(url);                
            jblV4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img4));
            url = this.getClass().getResource(accion[i++]);
            Image img5 = ImageIO.read(url);                                
            jblV5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img5));
            url = this.getClass().getResource(accion[i++]);
            /*Solo hay 6 imagenes en el array
            Image img6 = ImageIO.read(url);                                
            jblV6.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img6));
            url = this.getClass().getResource(accion[i++]);
            Image img7 = ImageIO.read(url);                                
            jblV7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img7));
            url = this.getClass().getResource(accion[i++]);
            Image img8 = ImageIO.read(url);                                
            jblV8.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img8));*/
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
            break;
    }
   
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, me sirvió demasiado tu respuesta.

Comment: Excelente @user97805 saludos!